# Python - convert set-cookies response to dict of cookies

Tags: python, cookies, python-3.3

How to convert the `response['set-cookie']` output string from `httplib2` response like

```
"cookie1=xxxyyyzzz;Path=/;Expires=Wed, 03-Feb-2015 08:03:12 GMT;Secure;HttpOnly, cookie2=abcdef;Path=/;Secure"
```

to

```
{'cookie1':'xxxyyyzzz','cookies2':'abcdef'}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Seems like a simple case of splitting a string on separators, moreover [the `set-cookie` header syntax](http://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc6265#page-8) does not allow separators within the cookie name _or_ value, so you wouldn't even need to bother with parsing quoting constructs.

Comment: If you used requests, you could just use `response.cookies` and get back a dictionary.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`http.cookies`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookies.html):

```
>>> c = "cookie1=xxxyyyzzz;Path=/;Expires=Wed, 03-Feb-2015 08:03:12 GMT;Secure;HttpOnly, cookie2=abcdef;Path=/;Secure"
>>> from http.cookies import SimpleCookie
>>> cookie = SimpleCookie()
>>> cookie.load(c)
>>> cookie
<SimpleCookie: cookie1='xxxyyyzzz' cookie2='abcdef'>
>>> {key: value.value  for key, value in cookie.items()}
{'cookie1': 'xxxyyyzzz', 'cookie2': 'abcdef'}
```

Comment: Excellent. This really should be a method `as_dict` on the BaseCookie class!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why , need some help:
Python 3.7.6 (default, Dec 30 2019, 19:38:26)
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> `c = "cookie1=xxxyyyzzz;Path=/;Expires=Wed, 03-Feb-2015 08:03:12 GMT;Secure;HttpOnly, cookie2=abcdef;Path=/;Secure"`

>>> `from http.cookies import SimpleCookie`

>>> `cookie = SimpleCookie()`

>>> `cookie.load(c)`

>>> `cookie`

`<SimpleCookie: >`

>>> `cookie.items()`

`dict_items([])`

>>>

Comment: @RickyChan, How about post a separated question instead of commenting here?  Seems some question text are truncated.   BTW, you're trying to parse expired http-only cookie.

Comment: This doesn't work using **Python 3.10.0**, the generated cookie is empty (it does work with a single cookie, but not with string composed of two cookies).

Comment: Maybe its related to iOS because it works within docker, strange.

Comment: @cglacet, If I change `expires` date and remove `Secure`, `HttpOnly`, It still works. (tested with Python 3.11.2, in Linux).

Comment: Yes but it should work with everything on, its a bit strange but the documentation is not even clear on whether it is intended to work on multiple entries or not.

Answer (score 7):

```
def parse_dict_cookies(cookies):
    result = {}
    for item in cookies.split(';'):
        item = item.strip()
        if not item:
            continue
        if '=' not in item:
            result[item] = None
            continue
        name, value = item.split('=', 1)
        result[name] = value
    return result
```

Answer (score -2):

if you are using `requests`,
`response.cookies` is dict-like object

Comment: It is indeed a dict*like, but it doesn't represent response['set-cookie'].