# parse http response set cookie string in python

Tags: python-3.x, http, httpcookie

```
audit=value1; Version=1; Max-Age=31535999; Expires=Thu, 25-Jul-2019 17:20:26 GMT,c=1; httponly; Path=/
```

I am beginner in python. I have a string that contains the `http.response.set_cookie` captured using wireshark. I want to parse the cookies and save them in the database.

I used the code suggested by falsetrue in [Python - convert set-cookies response to array of cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522586/python-convert-set-cookies-response-to-array-of-cookies#21522721?newreg=8728468f402b439f81d85ce136b4ce13)

but unfortunately I did not know how to retreive the other cookie parameters like `"httponly" ,"domain","secure"`

Appreciate any help!

Thanks.